With Terraform, when using resource `aws_iam_access_key` and output to retrieve the secret key the result retrieved is "tostring(null)"
I am using Terraform aws provider and I want create IAM user access key using aws_iam_access_key{} resource. But I don't know how to retrieve the secret key. I create the resource like this:
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "main_user_access_key" {
  user = aws_iam_user.main_user.name
}

And then I use Terraform output block like that:
output "main_user_secret_key" {
  value = aws_iam_access_key.main_user_access_key.encrypted_ses_smtp_password_v4
  sensitive = true
}

And use another Terraform output block in the root module:
output "main_module_outputs" {
  value = module.main
}

But after doing all these steps all I get of output is "tostring(null)"
"main_user_secret_key" = tostring(null)

Has anyone encountered similar problem ? What am I doing wrong and how could this be solved ?

have you created this resource directly in terraform or imported it after the fact? The terraform docs say Resource attributes such as encrypted_secret, key_fingerprint, pgp_key, secret, ses_smtp_password_v4, and encrypted_ses_smtp_password_v4 are not available for imported resources as this information cannot be read from the IAM API.

I have created it directly in Terraform, not imported.

How did you verify the value is null in the output? Did you verify the value in the exported attribute?

The pgp_key argument in the aws_iam_access_key resource encrypts the secret access key using a PGP (Pretty Good Privacy) key. so when you include a pgp_key, Terraform provides encrypted versions of the secret key through attributes like encrypted_secret.
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "main_user_access_key" {
  user     = aws_iam_user.main_user.name
  pgp_key  = file("mykey.asc") # Path to your public PGP key
}

output "encrypted_secret_key" {
  value     = aws_iam_access_key.main_user_access_key.encrypted_secret
  sensitive = true
}

This will normally solve it out.

The problem was me not specifying the pgp_key argument and using encrypted_ses_smtp_password_v4 attribute instead of encrypted_secret in the output. I did not read the documentation carefully telling that the attribute will only be generated if pgp_key is specified.

Things seem to be working now and the secret key gets generated.
